# Android Studio IDE - Terminal Background Text Colors different from Terminal Background Color

Tags: android-studio, colors, terminal

I just recently installed Android Studio on my Windows 10 computer, and I am trying to resolve this dissonant background color issue in the built-in terminal. Screenshot [here](http://i60.tinypic.com/1zbrpmr.png). I have not had this problem when I used Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04.

The color of the text background is black, while the color of the console background is white.  This issue is not related to my using Git Bash as my terminal as it also occurs when I use Windows Command Prompt.

I have checked through Settings --> Editor --> Colors and Fonts --> Console Colors and was unable to find anything that would allow me to resolve the background colors. I have also tried changing the color scheme to something different (e.g. Darcula). Screenshot [here](http://i61.tinypic.com/2cmufk7.png). Additionally, I also tried to change the overall UI theme and still got identical results.

The terminal is ugly, but I would love to take advantage of its built-in conveniences for using Git. The Android logcat output and Gradle messages look perfectly fine. How can I fix this so that the text and console background colors are the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for a while too.
From experience, the terminal takes the colors of the Windows console.  Not that very well however that was the only way that I could do the required changes.
Open a cmd window in windows and on the main menu go to defaults.
Change the colors and save. Next terminal in Android Studio will change on next instance.
The colors won't follow exactly so one needs some experimenting. Best results I got with black text on white background.