# Android studio terminal bug

Tags: android-studio

I can't see anything when I type in android studio's terminal. I see the cursor blinking and I can select lines till top but when I copy and paste it somewhere no texts are being pasted [what I checked].
There is no problem with any other log windows.[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9666.jpg) [IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7r77.jpg)

Comment: This might be of interest to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954437/cant-type-into-android-studios-built-in-terminal

Comment: Windows 7 => no such options as said in above forum

Comment: my cursor still blinking, but I can't see anything. When typing, the cursor does moves but not visible anything  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: stupid question but have you restarted android studio or reinstalled it

Comment: re-installed. had java sdk problem previously and I couldn't open the Android studio. It not starting either not showing any error message as well. So completely removed application and it's sdk file from android/sdk. Installed a new studio now with everything downloaded and updated

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with your font color settings. It seems like in Windows the terminal takes the colors of the Windows console. Check this answer: [Android Studio IDE - Terminal Background Text Colors different from Terminal Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821284/android-studio-ide-terminal-background-text-colors-different-from-terminal-bac/36732017#36732017)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)